# getting a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when using react native webview to go to localhost:9000/login

Tags: android, webview, react-native

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to this and trying to understand.

I have my node server running on localhost:9000, and I'm trying to get webview working.  Here's what I'm trying to return -

```
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <WebView
          ref={'webview'}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          style={styles.webView}
          source={{uri: 'http://localhost:9000/login'}}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
        />
      </View>
```

However, this doesn't work because I get the following error:

`Encountered an error loading page Object {canGoForward: false, code: -6, canGoBack: false, description: "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED", loading: false…}canGoBack: falsecanGoForward: falsecode: -6description: "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"loading: falsetarget: 9title: ""url: "http://localhost:9000/login"__proto__: ObjectreactConsoleError @ ExceptionsManager.js:76console.error @ YellowBox.js:48onLoadingError @ WebView.android.js:300proxiedMethod @ createPrototypeProxy.js:44invokeGuardedCallback @ ReactErrorUtils.js:26executeDispatch @ EventPluginUtils.js:87executeDispatchesInOrder @ EventPluginUtils.js:110executeDispatchesAndRelease @ EventPluginHub.js:42executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ EventPluginHub.js:53forEachAccumulated @ forEachAccumulated.js:26processEventQueue @ EventPluginHub.js:215runEventQueueInBatch @ ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:18handleTopLevel @ ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:29(anonymous function) @ ReactNativeEventEmitter.js:122perform @ Transaction.js:136batchedUpdates @ ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:63batchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:97_receiveRootNodeIDEvent @ ReactNativeEventEmitter.js:121receiveEvent @ ReactNativeEventEmitter.js:135__callFunction @ MessageQueue.js:185(anonymous function) @ MessageQueue.js:89guard @ MessageQueue.js:43callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:88onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:39`

The webview works fine when I put source uri as http://google.com or something.  Can someone help?  Thanks

Comment: try finding your computer's IP address using either ( ifconfig | grep inet ) in mac terminal or ( ipconfig/ALL ) in windows cmd. One of these should work as the WebView uri: exhttp://194.178.1.2:4242/my-local-endpoint

Answer (score 17, accepted):

localhost will be the Android device itself. To access your host OS from within the Android emulator you can use `10.0.2.2:9000` or your actual IP address.

Comment: thanks Daniel.  I actually had to put my computer's local_IP:port to use it.  :)

Comment: Perfect solution.  That was a duh moment.

Comment: 100% correct. Works well for my localhost server.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I prefer just to do `adb reverse tcp:9000 tcp:9000`